# Add function to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
var PROMO = PROMO || {};

PROMO.Base = (function () {
  var _self = this;

  var Init = function () {
    WireEvents();
  };

  var WireEvents = function () {
   //wire up events
  };

} ());
```

In the same file I have the code to call the above function

I am trying to get to an end point where I can use the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    PROMO.Base.Init();
 });
```

this gives the error

```
Cannot call method 'Init' of undefined
```

Now I know there are many ways to write javascript, but in this case I want to be able to call my functions, or least the Init method in the way shown above.

Comment: You never actually assigned the function stored in `Init` to `PROMO.Base.Init`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var PROMO = PROMO || {};

PROMO.Base = (function () {
  var _self = this;

  var Init = function () {
    WireEvents();
  };

  var WireEvents = function () {
   //wire up events
  };

  var reveal = {
        Init: Init        
  };

  return reveal;

} ());
```

You need to return the public facing functions. See updated code.

Comment: @alex23 this; didn't have anything to do with the problem at hand, so I ignored and or didn't pay much attention. ;)

Answer (score 5):

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/RXy8N/1/) with both patterns, using IIFE and direct attribution.

Using `var` makes the definition private and your function is returning nothing. Use this:

```
PROMO.Base = {
    Init: function() {
    },
    WireEvents: function() {
    };
};
```

You are wrapping the definition with an IIFE(Immediately Executed Function Expression). So your `PROMO.Base` object will be assigned the value of that `(function(){//blabla})();` returns. But your function doesn't have a `return` statement. By default it will return `undefined`.

Which is way your `PROMO.Base` will be `undefined` and you get this:

```
Cannot call method 'Init' of undefined
```

If you really want that IIFE:

```
var PROMO = PROMO || {};
// NEVER use _self = this inside static functions, it's very dangerous.
// Can also be very misleading, since the this object doesn't point to the same reference.
// It can be easily changed with Function.prototype.call and Function.prototype.apply
PROMO.Base = (function () {

    _PROMO = {
        Init : function () {
            document.body.innerHTML += "itworks";
        },
        WireEvents : function () {
   //wire up events
        }
    }
    return _PROMO;
} ());
PROMO.Base.Init();
```

**Update**

The better and easier pattern is to simply assign the functions to `PROMO.Base`. Dully note you should not capitalize static functions, but only constructors. So if something is not meant to be instantiated, don't call it `Init`, it should be `init`. That is the convention.

```
var PROMO = {};
PROMO.Base = {};
PROMO.Base.init = function() {
    console.log("this works");
};
PROMO.Base.wireEvents = function() {
    console.log("this is a static function too");
};
```

Comment: +1 not me; this is my preferred method, even though Drew's method is also valid.

Comment: ...and now you went and added the return. again, I feel that both methods are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach it to the `window` object like ...

```
window.PROMO = (function($, _){

// this will access PROMO.Base 
PROMO.Base = {
    // inner functions here
    Init:{}
};

})(jQuery, _);
```

Then load it as you do.

Or if you depend from jQuery

```
(function($){
    var PROMO = {
        // inner functions
        Init: function(){},
        WireEvents: function(){}
    };

    $.PROMO = PROMO;
})(jQuery);
```

On DOM ready

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var promo = $.PROMO || undefined;
    promo.Base.Init();
});
```