# Best way to privately scope Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently writing all javascript functionality of a certain page in JQuery's `document.ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var one, two, three;
    function f1(par1) {}
    function f2() {}
        ...
});
```

I feel that this isn't optimal or according to Javascript best practices. What I need is a **private** scope for the page's functionality, nothing needs to be called externally.

## I've seen a number of different ways:

### [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js)

```
(function(window) { 
    var anObj = {};
    ... 
    window.functionality = anObj;
}(window));
```

A function that is self-invoked with the `window` as parameter, then setting the `functionality` object of your application on it.

### [Codemirror source](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/blob/master/lib/codemirror.js)

```
window.functionality = (function() {
   var functionality = {};
   ...
   return functionality;
}());
```

Very similar to what jQuery does, but setting the functionality object indirectly on `window` by making a self-invoking function return something first.

### [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16496922/1313143)

```
var functionality = {};
(function(obj) { obj.f1 = ... }(functionality));
```

Creating a local variable (instead of on `window`), and setting its content inside a self-invoked function (why?)

### [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881515/1313143)

```
var functionality = { 
    f1: function(){}, 
    f2: function(){}
}
```

Pretty much the same as the previous thing but setting the contents without a self-invoking function (again why use or not use the self invoking function?).

## So... which way is best?

Comment: With private functionality, do you mean functionality that is only run/seen on a specific page?

Comment: @TJ yes, it is the javascript that controls the page during its lifetime, but should not be reachable by other javascript also on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the **module pattern** for this, where a page is treated as a module. There is a lot of information about the javascript module pattern on the web. Have a look at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html.

I've used an example from the [link](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) and modified it a bit:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.PageX = (function () {
    var my = {},
        privateVariable = 1;

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    my.moduleProperty = 1;
    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        // ...
    };

    return my;
}());
```

What is happening here, is that a set of properties and methods is defined and namespaced to `MyApp.PageX`, `MyApp` being the **global**. So this will work:

```
MyApp.PageX.moduleProperty; // 1
MyApp.PageX.moduleMethod();
```